# ng-class have class on first row of table and remove it on ng-click

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I am using angular js to display a table. When the page loads I want the first row of the table to be highlighted, then when you click on another row of the table I want to remove the hightlighted class.

I've managed to get it to add the class on the top row using

```
 ng-class="{'selected-row':$first}"
```

but then I'm not able to remove it. I'd lke to be able to pass a variable from $scope, like this, so that I can change the value on click...

controller....

```
 $scope.changeClass = function(){
  if ($scope.myClass === "selected-row"){
    $scope.myClass = "off";
    window.alert('change class here to remove highlight!!!');
  } else {
    $scope.myClass = "selected-row";
    window.alert('change it back!!');
  }
```

html....

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-click="changeClass()" ng-class="{myClass:$first}">
```

This doesn't work and I can't figure out the syntax (if it's possible!!) Any ideas?

Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Zs1r6DQcc3vaUDjzkUh8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` along with an array which keeps track of your row index to achieve this

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('ngTableApp', ['ngTable'])
          .controller('selectFilterController', function($scope, $filter, $q, NgTableParams) {
            var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                        {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                        {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                        {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                        {name: "Enos", age: 34}
                    ];


    $scope.class = "selected-row";
    $scope.changeClass = function(index){
     $scope.selected=[];  
     $scope.selected[index]=true;
    };
    $scope.changeClass(0); 
            $scope.names = [{id: "", title: ""}, {id: 'Moroni', title: 'Moroni'}, {id: 'Enos', title: 'Enos'}, {id: 'Nephi', title: 'Nephi'}];
            $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({page: 1, count: 10}, {data: data});
            
          })
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
.selected-row{
  border:solid purple 3px;
}

.off{
  border:none;
}

.table-striped > tbody > tr:hover{
  border:solid purple 3px;
}

.table-striped > tbody > tr:active{
  border:solid purple 3px;
}


.table-striped > tbody > tr:focus{
  border:solid purple 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.7" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ngTableApp">
    <h1>NgTable with select filters</h1>
    <div ng-controller="selectFilterController">
      <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped ng-scope ng-table" show-filter="true">
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-click="changeClass($index)"  ng-class="{'selected-row':selected[$index]}">
          <!--<tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-click="changeClass()" ng-class="{myClass:$first}">  -->
            <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{name: 'select'}" filter-data="names" sortable="'name'">{{ row.name }}</td>
            <td data-title="'Age'" filter="{age: 'text'}" sortable="'age'">{{ row.age }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've adjusted your `ng-repeat` to track each item by $index. Starting out we'll set the active row index to 0 with the following line:

```
$scope.activeRow = 0
```

Then in the click event of a row, we'll set the active row to the currently clicked row:

```
$scope.setActive = (index) => {
  $scope.activeRow = index;
}
```

Then to see which row needs to be highlighted, calling the following function in your `ng-class` makes the magic happen:

```
$scope.isActive = (index) => {
  return $scope.activeRow === index; 
}
```

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/OMpcDg5V8TVHkxHUIXUQ?p=preview